# Object that belongs to multiple other objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Take the following associations based on a Feedback model:

feedback.rb

```
belongs_to :buyer, :foreign_key => :buyer_id, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :seller, :foreign_key => :seller_id, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :listing
```

The reverse associations are `has_many`

When `creating` the feedback object it could be 'anchored' to any of the above other objects (e.g. `buyer.feedbacks`, `seller.feedbacks`, `listing.feedbacks`)

---

Say in this example we want to primarily link it with the buyer and so `nest the feedback routes within user` and then build a create action in the Feedbacks controller that looks something like:

```
current_user.feedbacks.new(feedback_params)
```

#### or is it more appropriate/correct to reference?

```
buyer.feedbacks.new(feedback_params)
```

#### Is this even valid without an explicit buyer model?

---

#### What is the Rails way to then incorporate the other `belongs_to` relationships?

It's not a nested attribute (as the other objects already exist).

#### Should I be merging in the other params with something like?

```
params.require(:feedback).permit(:rating, :comment).merge(seller_id: @seller.id, listing_id: @listing.id)
```

---

One approach I have seen is the use of a `before_validation` filter in this sort of manner (from a different domain) like this:

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :host, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :inquiry
  belongs_to :room

before_validation :set_room_and_guest_id

def set_room_and_guest_id
  self.room ||= self.inquiry.room if self.inquiry
  self.user ||= self.inquiry.user if self.inquiry
end
```

I have spent a long time reading related posts about this today as well as the Rails documentation and have not been able to find a conclusion.

Comment: I think you want to use a polymorphic association here. https://launchschool.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails read about it

Answer (score 0):

There's no "right" way here - just build the system you want. It sounds like a `Buyer` has `Feedback` about a `Listing` sold by a `Seller`, so it's completely reasonable to link all of those things together (or at least Amazon hasn't discovered a reason not to yet, and that's a pretty good sign).

The simplest "Rails way" you're probably looking for is to include all the relevant IDs in the feedback form. That does make them accessible to people who might want to fiddle, eg. by setting the seller/listing IDs to their own and leaving fraudulent positive feedback. You can combat that by merging `@seller` and `@listing` in the controller like you've mentioned, or with validations that the reviewer has bought the item, can't leave more than one, etc.

It also sounds like there might be room for a `Transaction` object here, representing the link between `Buyer`, `Seller` and `Listing`. Maybe the `Feedback` belongs on the `Transaction`.

Overall, I'd say you've been paralyzed by all the options available to you, and the best thing to do is pick one and run with it. When it's not clear which direction is best, that's often because you don't have all the information you need yet, but once you try something out you'll quickly learn more. Once you realize "Oh, I should have done this this other way", the beauty of code is you can change it.

Comment: "you've been paralyzed by all the options available to you" - very true! - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume every listing has exactly one buyer and one seller, and there can be exactly zero or one feedbacks per listing. Then you might be confusing things a bit by linking the feedback directoy to buyer and seller. The normalized way would be to relate the feedback to the listing and nothing else. Then all questions go away.

(Note, you can then still get the buyer (or seller) directly from the feedback by using a `:through` rails relation.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [Polymorfic Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

> A slightly more advanced twist on associations is the polymorphic association. With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association.